# JQuery append button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to JQuery I have tried to read other solutions here in stackoverflow but I don't understand it yet. Could you please help me?

I have a button that is appended onto the page after calling a function addQuestion. When I click the button it does not work but the button with same id created in html does work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <title>Javascript</title>
  </head>

  <body>

  <div id="header">
    <h1>My Site</h1>
  </div>
  
  <div id="content">
    <p ><h2>Question: </h2></p>
      <strong>question 1:</strong> how old am I? <br>
      a) 18 <br>
      b) 17 <br>
      c) 22 <br>
    <br>
    <input id="myAnswer" type="text">
    <button id="addOne">answer</button>
     </div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"> </script>

 <script>

  $('#addOne').click(function() {
    var theAnswer = $('#myAnswer').val();
    alert(theAnswer);
  });
  


  function addQuestion(questionNo, task, reply){
    $('#content').append("<br><br><br>" + questionNo +  task + "<br>" + reply + "<br>"
    + '<input id="myAnswer" type="text">' + '<button id="addOne">answer</button>' );
   }

 
   addQuestion("<strong> question 2: </strong>", "what's my name", "a) Will <br> b) Peter <br> c) Jeff " );
 


 </script>
 

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use delegated-events and Make sure that HTML element IDs must be unique for every element in the page,

Comment: And don't forget to wrap your function calls with `$(document).ready(function() { /* ... */ });`...

Answer (score 1):

First use classes not ID's for that button. Secondly, you need a future-proof event listener. Third, namespace your components so there is some contextual binding:

```
  // Notice we map the answer to the button with a data attribute.
  function addQuestion(id, questionNo, task, reply){
    $('#content').append("<br><br><br>" + questionNo +  task + "<br>" + reply + "<br>"
    + '<input id="myAnswer-' + id + '" type="text">' + '<button class="addOne" data-answer-id="myAnswer-' + id + '">answer</button>' );
   }

  // Notice we bind click on the static container and delegate to a dynamic element.
  $('#content').on('click', '.addOne', function() {
    var theAnswer = $('#' + $(this).data('answer-id')).val();
    alert(theAnswer);
  });

  // Example add - pass in 2 for an ID
  addQuestion(2, "<strong> question 2: </strong>", "what's my name", "a) Will <br> b) Peter <br> c) Jeff " );
```

Working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/x231eLc8/

Comment: Thank you. You saved me from few hours of brainstorming. You made me smarter and now I get it :-).

Answer (score 0):

as your button gets added dynamically, you need to use [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach event handler to your newly created button and ID's should be unique, so make sure you use different id in case you are generating multiple buttons:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#addOne', function() {
        var theAnswer = $('#myAnswer').val();
        alert(theAnswer);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I know that it's a stupid question. I  just started and appreciate your help. <3

Answer (score -1):

> **Hi, the problem is that you can't have two buttons with the same ID .
>   You can create two different buttons .. and create a new script.**

```
<script>

$('#addOne').click(function() {var theAnswer = $('#myAnswer').val();alert(theAnswer);});

$('#addTwo').click(function() {var theAnswer = $('#myAnswer2').val();alert(theAnswer);});

function addQuestion(questionNo, task, reply){$('#content').append("<br><br><br>" + questionNo +  task + "<br>" + reply + "<br>"+ '<input id="myAnswer2" type="text">' + '<button id="addTwo">answer</button>' );};

addQuestion("<strong> question 2: </strong>", "what's my name", "a) Will <br> b) Peter <br> c) Jeff ");

</script>
```

> OR use classes and the "this" word.